# breadcrumbs for multi-level url

Tags: php, yii

I want to create multi-level breadcrumbs, like if user go to  Home->Step1->step2->step3 page then goes to Step4 :  i want  to see my breadcrumbs Home:->step1->step2-step3->->step4.

Here is my code :

```
<?php 
    $path = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],PHP_URL_PATH);
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    $stepname='Step'.$step->step_code;
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
        echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
        for ($i = 2; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
            if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
                echo("<a href=\"");
                for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) 
                {
                    echo $parts[$j]."/";
                };
                echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $parts[$i])."</a> » ");
            }
        };
    };  
?>
```

but its  show only Home->step3>step4 ,its not show step2 and step3.
Actually I want multilevel breadcrumbs.

Comment: Change $i = 2 to $i = 0 , So for loop will count from 0 to increment. will add rest of the "/" which goes through infinite level.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Yii built in class [CBreadcrumbs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBreadcrumbs).

Besides that, you have logic error in your `if` statement. Home will show only if there are no other items.

Move `if` after `echo` home:

```
echo("home");

if (count($parts) > 2)
{
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
# Rewritten Ajmal PraveeN
    $path = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],PHP_URL_PATH);
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    $stepname='Step'.$step->step_code;
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
        echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
            if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
                echo("<a href=\"");
                for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) 
                {
                    echo $parts[$j]."/";
                };
                echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $parts[$i])."</a> » ");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The above code works fine with slash directories
ex: If php explodes a path is /home/website/public or Infinite path levels, the script generates what you are looking for ;)
Changes I made are `$i = 2` to `$i = 0`
and A suggestion instead of str_replace use CSS styling for the `»`

Thank you..!